# Combine jQuery-ui datepicker's localization and initialization parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, localization, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to have my localized datepicker not allow certain dates picking.

Localization:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["fr"]);
```

No weekends :

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends })
```

I cannot figure out how to combine both?

Comment: @neoascetic, thanks, made typo when pasting here. Still not sure how to solve.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$.datepicker.regional` attribute attribute holds an array of localizations; which themselves are "presets" of the [datepicker options](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/). To append your options (overwriting if necessary):

```
// use $.extend to merge preset options plus your options
$("#datepicker1")
    .datepicker($.extend({}, $.datepicker.regional.fr, {
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
    }));

// initialize the datepicker, then use .datepicker("option", options) method twice
$("#datepicker2")
    .datepicker()
    .datepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional.fr)
    .datepicker("option", "beforeShowDay", $.datepicker.noWeekends);
```

[**Demo (see example 5)**](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2013/01/jquery-ui-datepicker-examples.html)